# How to access data on the third level of a JSON array Object

Tags: javascript, json

I am taking a chance in posting this message for help after looking through over 20+ questions. I could not find an array like the one that I have.

The good news is that I have half of the data that I want from the array. I am missing one last piece of information.

Here is my code.

```
xhr.onload = function() {
    if(this.status === 200) {
        let response = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        console.log(response);
        response.rows.forEach(function(row) {
            output += `
            <div>
                <p>${row.number_e164}, ${row.regional_data.rate_center}, ${row.regional_data.rate_center.state}</p>
            </div>
            `;
        })
        document.getElementById('numberdisplay').innerHTML = output;
    }
}
xhr.open('POST', 'provision_helper.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
xhr.send(data);
```

Here is a portion of the array.

[image: screenshot of returned object]

This displays the number rate center but not the number.

```
 <p>${row.number_e164}, ${row.regional_data.rate_center}, ${row.regional_data.rate_center.state}</p>
```

I have tried

```
 <p>${row.number_e164}, ${row.regional_data.rate_center}, ${row.regional_data.rate_center['state']}</p>
```

That did not work and just adding state does not work. I can see that the regional data has a different structure. How do I access the state and country iso inside the regional data?

Comment: `row.regional_data.state`. Why do you think `state` is inside `rate_center`?

Comment: They're both at the same level.

Comment: Your question says that the number isn't being displayed. But it looks like it should be the state that's not showing.

Comment: Thank you. I could not see that they are on the same level. Sometimes it takes someone else pointing out the obvious to get past where I am stuck in the build process. Thank you.  =^)8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to reference them as being inside `rate_center`, which isn't correct. Try `row.regional_data.state` and `row.regional_data.country_iso` instead.